# PHP weird behavior: false OR true returns false

Tags: php

I encountered a weird bug in PHP 5.4.3

```
var_dump(false OR true); // boolean true // OK

$a = false OR true;
var_dump($a); // boolean false // !!????

$a = true OR false;
var_dump($a); // boolean true // OK

$a = false || true;
var_dump($a); // boolean true // OK
```

Does anyone know how the second result came up!?

Thanks :)

Comment: Already discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414504/the-strange-ways-of-the-or-in-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`or` and `and` have a *lower* [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) then `=`.

This is effectively:

```
($a = false) OR true;
($a = true) OR false;
$a = (false || true);
```

Note that this is the reason people tend to use `or die()` constructs (which really, really, really should be `or trigger_error()`'s, `die`'s on errors have NO place in code): if the result of the left hand assignment (the resulting value in `$a` in this case) is `false`, perform the right hand side.

Compare:

```
$a = false or print("what is going on?");
// prints 'what is going on?', $a === false
$a = true or print("what is going on?");
// prints nothing, $a === true
```

Comment: Wow, ok. I would have never thought of that, I was told that || and OR were exactly the same operators. I learned something today, thanks!

Comment: @ThomasW: or you mean to say operator precedence is a thing only PHP has? (BTw, [perl, in many ways in inspiration for PHP, has it too](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity)). There are enough valid problems with PHP, there is no need to blame it for a devs inability to read the documentation too.

Comment: Well, I guess "statement OR" is kinda intended to have a lower precedence -- to enable "OR die()" type structures. But this seems an ugly substitute for proper exception-handling. (And reading the Perl manual seems like a breath of fresh air & readable sanity, compared to the ghastly, uninformative & hacky PHP docs  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php ).

Answer (score 2):

It is called the precedence of the operators.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

So

```
$a = false OR true;
```

is the same as

```
($a = false) OR true;
```

etc...